# Doctrine 2 - COALESCE and CONCAT

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have this DQL Query:

```
$repository->createQuery("SELECT f.id, COALESCE(f.name, 
CONCAT(f.floor_number, ' NP')) as name FROM ".__NAMESPACE__.'\\Floor f 
WHERE f.building = ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, $this->building);
```

but it doesn't work - i get

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 36: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '('
```

The reason is usage of CONCAT inside COALESCE.... is there any way how to make this work (without native query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was [fixed](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/1e1f34f9cb733a708e57fb8e5d5797a011a663af) by an improvement to the DQL parser in Doctrine 2.4. Upgrade to 2.4 and this query will work.